# Open PuTTY and run shell script on server

Tags: vba, excel, shell, putty

I want to open Putty from local machine, automatically login to the server, and run shell script on the same session of putty using Excel VBA Script.
The code below works fine to open putty.

```
Sub open_putty()
    Dim UserName 'assign user name
    Dim Passwrd 'assign password
    Dim TaskID As Long
    pc1 = "C:\Users\Desktop\putty.exe -ssh " & UserName & "@servernamee -pw " & Passwrd
    TaskID = Shell(pc1, 1)
End Sub
```

However, I'm not able to run the shell script test.sh on the same session.  The script is in the default location after login.
How can I run the shell script on the server using Excel VBA.

Comment: Well done for the first question here !

Comment: still I am not able to find solution of that question. could you reopen it. shared solution is not working.

Comment: Nobody has closed this question I believe. :). See Marc's final comment. That could be of some help..

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you need to use the `-m` parameter.

Like this:

```
pc1 = "C:\Users\Desktop\putty.exe -ssh " & UserName & "@servernamee -pw " & Passwrd & " -m c:\temp\test.sh"
TaskID = Shell(pc1, 1)
```

You might also consider use `plink.exe`, which is the command line connection utility.

Comment: Thanks Marc. I need to run shell script, which is located at remote server. while i am using & "-m /home/test.sh"  then error message pop up as "unable to open command file /home/test.sh". could you please suggest me any solution apart from plink.exe.

Comment: is that the full path to the script you're trying to run on the remote machine? I assume putty/plink runs the series of commands you provide in your local script, which could actually call the remote script, no? I probably can't offer a lot more, as I was just going off of what I read on the web.

Comment: pc1 = "C:\Users\Desktop\putty.exe -ssh " & UserName & "@server -pw " & Passwrd
pc2 = "/home/test.sh"
TaskID1 = Shell(pc1, 1)
TaskID2 = Shell(pc2, 1)......While executing this code, It is showing Error message as "File not found" in the TaskID2.

Comment: If you're trying to use putty from a Windows machine (which I assume you are if you're using VBA), you need to specify a Windows path to a file that resides on the local Windows machine. You appear to have specified a `test.sh` file that resides on the remote machine, so of course that won't work.

Comment: if I am able to login to putty with userID and password successfully from the windows machine, There should be some command, so that I can run also any script on the putty. could you please check and suggest that we can solve via sendkeys and writeline functions. Is there any command to copy text data on the putty command line from Excel VBA script(discussed eariler) and hit enter. so that we can run the required shell script.

Comment: @Marc Is there any parameter rather than `-m` to execute any command like I want to execute `ls` command after connecting to target server.

Comment: @harun24hr, if you write `ls` into the script, then your script will execute `ls`.  You can write whatever executable commands you want into that script.

Comment: Then what will be format means what will full code to run ls command. Can you please put a line here exactly.

Comment: You need to create a script file (batch file, etc.) that contains the commands you want to run. The `-m` parameter identifies that script file. Put your commands in that file.